# Phylo correlogram in R bootstrapping error?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am trying to create a phylo correlogram based on my data using `phyloCorrelogram` from the `phylosignal` package in order to test for presence of a phylogenetic signal. My data is in the so-called `phylo4d` format and is called `tree`.

Now, when I run `phyloCorrelogram(tree)`, I am returned the following error:

```
library("phylobase")
library("ape")
library("phylosignal") # contains phyloCorrelogram()

> phyloCorrelogram(tree, ci.bs = 10, n.points = 10)
Error in boot::boot(X, function(x, z) moranTest(xr = x[z], Wr = prop.table(Wi[z,  : 
  no data in call to 'boot'
```

I have already done an elaborate search on the internet to look for ways how to solve this issue, but without success.

Since the dimension of the data that I am using is too large to post it here, I have posted my data in `.rda` format on [dropbox](http://dropbox.com/s/rnd62umvrom1n5i/tree.rda?dl=0).

Does anyone know the flaw?

Comment: can we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnd62umvrom1n5i/tree.rda?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no data associated to your tree. Your tree is a phylo4d object which has the "tree" information but no data attached to it. You need something like that

```
library(phylobase)
g1 <- as(geospiza_raw$tree, "phylo4")
geodata <- geospiza_raw$data
g2 <- phylo4d(g1, geodata)
pc <- phyloCorrelogram(g2)
```